# Dyamic find in shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

Here is the problem I'm working on

I have a bunch of files in different directories which are all in one root dir. I have scan all these folders and pick up the files in them avoiding some specific sub-dirs. These folder that I have to avoid will come from a config file. For the purpose I prepared this find command (with some help)

```
find ${ROOT}/au* -type f -not \( -path '*auction123/incoming*' -o -path '*autobase/incoming*'* \)
```

Here ROOT will also come from the config file. can I also provide a place holder for this

```
-path '*auction123/incoming*' -o -path '*autobase/incoming*'*
```

so that I can add any number of folders that has to be ignored in the find. I read at some places that find with grep is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
find ${ROOT}/au* -type f | grep -v -f files_containing_list_of_ignore_directories
```

Where `files_containing_list_of_ignore_directories` places each directory you wish to ignore on a separate line (without the wildcards `*`).

(This is what `files_containing_list_of_ignore_directories` should look like:)

```
auction123/incoming
autobase/incoming
...
```

**Explanation:**

- `find ${ROOT}/au* -type f`: recursively find all files under any directories that match `au*` in `${ROOT}`
- `|` is the pipe operator in shell: it means "take whatever is output to `stdout` from the previous command (in this case, `find`) and feed that output to `stdin` of the next command (in this case, `grep`)
- `grep`: invoke grep, a tool used for searching
- `-v`: Use the `--invert-match` option for `grep`. Basically it means to "filter out" anything that is matched.
- `-f files_containing_list_of_ignore_directories`: Supply a file that holds the list of patterns you want grep to match (and filter out in this case).

Comment: Do you mean something like this find ${ROOT}/au* -type f | grep -v -f auction123/incoming , find ${ROOT}/au* -type f | grep -v -f autobase/incoming. etc...Can't we have all the ignore folders listed in a single find stmt?

Comment: @Ravi No, I meant to put the list of all the directories you wish to ignore in a plain text file called `files_containing_list_of_ignore_directories`, one per line.